# source usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh never works

Tags: python, virtualenv, virtualenvwrapper, virtual-environment

I've tried many recipes to install virtualenvwrapper (no idea what I'm doing btw) and nothing seems to be working. I uninstalled and reinstalled virtualenv and virtualenv wrapper, unset all the relevant environmental variables every time so there would be no residue from my other attempts, etc.

I tried

```
pip3 install virtualenvwrapper
export WORKON_HOME=$HOME/programming/workspace
source /usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

and get

```
ImportError: No module named importlib_metadata
virtualenvwrapper.sh: There was a problem running the initialization hooks.

If Python could not import the module virtualenvwrapper.hook_loader,
check that virtualenvwrapper has been installed for
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python and that PATH is
set properly.
```

here are my environmental variables

```
Azazel:/ eez$ printenv
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_SCRIPT=/usr/local/bin/virtualenvwrapper.sh
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PROJECT_FILENAME=.project
TERM_PROGRAM=Apple_Terminal
SHELL=/bin/bash
TERM=xterm-256color
TMPDIR=/var/folders/r7/9br4shwj5rl6pyt4xhx28p4h0000gn/T/
TERM_PROGRAM_VERSION=433
OLDPWD=/usr
TERM_SESSION_ID=56FC5732-D008-41C1-97F3-543AE903CF88
USER=eez
SSH_AUTH_SOCK=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.82rAHEaI9a/Listeners
WORKON_HOME=/Users/programming/workspace
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python
PATH=/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.8/bin:/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/bin:/Volumes/Selaphiel/Programming_not_work/miniconda3/bin:/opt/local/bin:/opt/local/sbin:/Users/eez/.rbenv/shims:/Users/eez/.rbenv/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/texbin:/opt/X11/bin:/usr/local/git/bin:/Users/eez/bin
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_HOOK_DIR=/Users/programming/workspace
LaunchInstanceID=12C70771-218F-496C-AA53-EB37A508D0EC
PWD=/
LANG=en_US.UTF-8
XPC_FLAGS=0x0
XPC_SERVICE_NAME=0
SHLVL=1
HOME=/Users
LOGNAME=eez
VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_WORKON_CD=1
DISPLAY=/private/tmp/com.apple.launchd.8uSx4Gu2zj/org.macosforge.xquartz:0
SECURITYSESSIONID=186a6
_=/usr/bin/printenv
```

if I type

```
source usr/local/virtualenvwrapper.sh
```

it says

```
-bash: usr/local/virtualenvwrapper.sh: No such file or directory
```

Then, even though this is not intended for macOS, since it seemed to refer to the same problem I tried the instructions at https://subscription.packtpub.com/book/big-data-and-business-intelligence/9781783555079/1/ch01lvl1sec10/installing-virtualenv-and-virtualenvwrapper

and I get this

```
sudo easy_install virtualenvwrapper
```

```
Searching for virtualenvwrapper
Best match: virtualenvwrapper 4.8.4
Processing virtualenvwrapper-4.8.4-py2.7.egg
virtualenvwrapper 4.8.4 is already the active version in easy-install.pth
Installing virtualenvwrapper_lazy.sh script to /usr/local/bin
Installing virtualenvwrapper.sh script to /usr/local/bin

Using /Library/Python/2.7/site-packages/virtualenvwrapper-4.8.4-py2.7.egg
Processing dependencies for virtualenvwrapper
Searching for importlib_metadata>=1.7.0
Reading https://pypi.org/simple/importlib_metadata/
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/2e/6d/4508b1922b1610f6646fd95681fa1b0c092df35ec14018218f4638b7342a/importlib_metadata-4.8.2.tar.gz#sha256=75bdec14c397f528724c1bfd9709d660b33a4d2e77387a3358f20b848bb5e5fb
Best match: importlib-metadata 4.8.2
Processing importlib_metadata-4.8.2.tar.gz
Writing /tmp/easy_install-qYLOF4/importlib_metadata-4.8.2/setup.cfg
Running importlib_metadata-4.8.2/setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir /tmp/easy_install-qYLOF4/importlib_metadata-4.8.2/egg-dist-tmp-FktdST
error: find_namespace: directive is unsupported on Python < 3.3
```

I notice that it's automatically installing with Python 2.7 even though I have 3.8 on my computer-- and I guess I'm not "allowed" to get rid of Python 2.7 without breaking things (which is a constant nuisance).

I'm so frustrated! This should be a couple-line install and I've been going at it for hours.

Comment: Make sure your PATH puts Python 3.8 _first_. Don't use aliases -- subprocess don't see shell aliases.

Comment: Also, `VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON=/usr/bin/python` is pointing at Python 2.7, the exact _wrong_ one. You should be setting `VIRTUALENVWRAPPER_PYTHON` to point to where Python 3.8 is.